# why the interval of invoking applyTransformation() is about 16ms?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

recently, I am researching the system implement of `android.view.animation.Animation`.

I override the Animation.applyTransformation() method, and log the invoking interval time, it's about 16ms.

16ms' interval means 60fps. This make the animation plays smoothly.

But why is 16ms? Who control this?

If I implement a animation thread to implement custom animation, I usually do `postDelayed(this, 16)`, so that my Thread will run at 60fps, each time post a message to `Handler` ,tell it to do some UI change on `Main Thread`.

How about android system?

Comment: Might be worth watching this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8m9sHdyXnE

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the [`Choreographer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Choreographer.html) class:

> Coordinates the timing of animations, input and drawing. The choreographer receives timing pulses (such as vertical synchronization) from the display subsystem then schedules work to occur as part of rendering the next display frame.

Comment: Note that applications don't normally need to use the class directly. Instead of `Handler#postDelayed(Runnable, long)` you can use `View#postOnAnimation(Runnable)` and that will schedule the `Runnable` command to be executed on the next display frame.